# d3: Chrome/Safari render transition of clipping mask and pattern strangely

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, cross-browser, clipping, voronoi

### Example

Please refer to the example for my following question:

http://jsfiddle.net/ssmvabxp/4/embedded/result/

Open it first with firefox, to see the wanted behaviour.
Then open it in chrome or safari to see the behaviour I am posting about.

### The Workflow

I am using the d3.voronoi function to calculate a voronoi diagram from coordinates.
Each coordinate gets its own circle by binding data, which visually consists of:
- white circular border
- centered portrait in the middle

Because I am using polygons/voronoi diagram, I had to use background patterns (with the portrait)
and had to cut them out with a clipping circle at each circles coordinates, so the portrait is visible
inside the circle.
This is how I (for this example) initially create the patterns. One for each circle:

```
function generateIcons(){
  // test: create 50 patterns for testing, all kirk images
  // ids: 1,2,3 … 50

  console.log("creating kirk test pattern");
  iconContainer = background.append("defs").attr("id", "mdef");

  for (var p_id = 1; p_id <= 50; p_id++) {

    iconContainer.append("pattern")
      .attr("id", "icon_" + p_id)
      .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
      .attr("PatternContentUnits","objectBoundingBox")
      .attr("height", circleSize*2)
      .attr("width", circleSize*2)
      .append("image")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("height", circleSize*2)
        .attr("width", circleSize*2)
        .attr("xlink:href", "images/kirk.jpg");
      }
  }
```

I fill the voronoi polygons with:

```
// create new voronoi paths, when new tags come in
   paths.enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", polygon)
  .style("fill", function(d){return "url(#icon_" + d.point.id + ")"; }) // load kirk pattern
    .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "path-"+d.point.id; })
  .attr("class", "voronoi-cut");
```

And clip them:

```
// create clip paths, when new tags come in
  clips.selectAll("clipPath")
      .data(mainData.tag[step], function(d){return d.id;})
    .enter().append("svg:clipPath")
      .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "clip-"+d.id;})
    .append("svg:circle")
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.loc[0]; })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.loc[1]; })
      .attr('r', circleSize);
```

When two those circles overlap, they merge (like cells (*biology*)), which is accomplished
with the voronois polygon. (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LUbK.png)

### The Issue

- when doing my update routine (every 2000ms), I calculate the new voronoi diagram from the new coordinates I read. When I want to move/transition the circles with the portraits that are created by clipping masks, I have to move:
- the whole pattern
- the clipping mask
- the white circle that surrounds the *cut-out* portraits

**This works alright in firefox! However in Chrome and Safari not even the white circles move smoothly. The transition of pattern/clipping mask doesn't seem to work at all.**
I have created a basic example of the problem (see on top)
I already tried to only move the white circles, which works great on all browsers. But when moving clipping masks and patterns comes into play, its getting very mixed between the three browsers.

Does anybody have an idea if this could be a browser related bug? It's a unusual situation, so it might not have occured to too man people.

Or am I doing some steps not quite right?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just fill the circles with the image pattern, why clip it at all?  Why move all the elements together, why not `g` them together and transform that into position?

Comment: @Mark I need to clip, because I want the *cut* from the voronoi diagram, or more precisely the polygon that is returned from `d3.geom.voronoi`. If I don't want to have the cut from the voronoi calculations, it works just like you said, without problems. That was the first version I had, but my collegue  wanted the circles to merge when overlapping, so we went for the voronoi diagram to calculate the *cuts* between circles.

I used this example as a starter for my visualization:
http://bl.ocks.org/njvack/1405439

Comment: @Mark
I tried your approach with `g` for clips and border circles. As expected the transition now works fine. however, I am not sure how to get the cut between two elements: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/ssmvabxp/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/ssmvabxp/13/).

To enable clipping and only see the circles, please uncomment lines *178-182* .

When clipping I want the cut from the voronoi diagram to be visible. Any hint would be appreciated :)